# How do I should choose my log compression type in apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, compression, gzip, snappy, lz4

I want to do compress data log in Apache Kafka. How do I know which one to choose? For me, performance and space is important.

Server.properties file

Compression.type = **snappy** , **gzip** , **lz4** vb. use.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's not really log compression you're looking for but message compression. Can you please change the title if my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anecdotally, [Uber uses zlib with MsgPack serialized messages](https://eng.uber.com/trip-data-squeeze/). However, you should perform your own benchmarks on your own hardware, network and storage (for example, those numbers were gotten using Python libraries)

Regarding the underlying serialization, [Avro serialization via a Schema Registry](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one/) allows you to have stricter schema definition rules than plaintext or JSON, and Avro generally pairs well with Snappy compression